# Converting an SQL Server database to an SQL Server Compact database. And back

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

Simple problem. I have an SQL Server database (MyData.mdf) and I want to convert it to a Compact database. (MyData.sdf) Just can't find the proper tool which can do this for me.

And I would also be able to convert the compact database back to a regular SQL Server database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't directly convertible from one to the other; many aspects of SQL Server aren't supported in SQL Compact.

You might consider using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to help manage the transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any hidden options from SQL Server Studio?

Comment: No but since SQL Server studio allows management of both normal SQL server and compact editions I'm sure there are some options which wouldn't be visible at first glance but would be somewhere as a suboption of import/export.